# Access SQL Insert entire row based on missing criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, sql-insert

I have two tables BYFIELD and EXTRAFIELDS
I am trying to insert missing rows based on two criteria- "campo" and "categoria". The rows have multiple fields (at least ten)
I want to add missing campo rows and missing categoria if the campo is there
This is all I have:

```
   strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblBYFIELD ([CAMPO], [CATEGORIA])" & _
            "SELECT [EXTRAFIELDS].[CAMPO], [EXTRAFIELDS].[CATEGORIA]" _
            "FROM [EXTRAFIELDS]" & _
            "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ***TOP*** 1" &_
            "FROM BYFIELD AS SIM"&_
            "WHERE EXTRAFIELDS.[CAMPO] = SIM.[CAMPO] AND EXTRAFIELDS.[CATEGORIA] = SIM.[CATEGORIA]);"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Table BYFIELD Example:
Campo   Categoria   Aceite  Gas  ETC...
Tintal   1PDP         0      0    0
Tintal   2PDNP        0      0    0

Table EXTRAFIELDS Example:
Campo   Categoria   Aceite   Gas  ETC...
Tintal    1PDP        0       0    0
Tintal    2PDNP       0       0    0
Tintal    3PD         0       0    0

I would like to insert the missing Tintal row that has 3PD in it.

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run the code - error, wrong results, nothing?

Why do you have *** around TOP? Why use TOP 1? You really want to return only 1 record? As @Andre said, data examples would be helpful. Your description doesn't really make sense.

Missing & on second line. Missing a space in front of _ and a space before " at end of each line.

```
"INSERT INTO tblBYFIELD ([CAMPO], [CATEGORIA]) " & _
     "SELECT [EXTRAFIELDS].[CAMPO], [EXTRAFIELDS].[CATEGORIA] " & _
     "FROM [EXTRAFIELDS] " & _
     "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 " & _
     "FROM BYFIELD AS SIM " & _
     "WHERE EXTRAFIELDS.[CAMPO] = SIM.[CAMPO] AND EXTRAFIELDS.[CATEGORIA] = SIM.[CATEGORIA]);"
```

This corrects syntax but not sure it will provide the results you want.

Did a test with the example data posted. Do you want to pull all fields? Assuming the fields in each table are the same names and in the same order in design, this works:
`INSERT INTO ByFields SELECT * FROM ExtraFields WHERE Campo & Categoria NOT IN (SELECT Campo & Categoria FROM ByFields);`
Otherwise, modify to specify the fields you want to populate and pull from.

Comment: I thought that I needed the Top 1. Can I just take that out? I have a table with fields going across- Campo Categoria aceite etc. For every Entry under Campo, there is one of 9 different entries in categoria. I want to add any missing campos that aren't included in the first table, but are included in the second table. Then I want to add any missing categories. EX: Campo Tintal Categoria 1PDP is missing for the table, I want to include that from the second table.

Comment: See revised answer.